# Did reducing this outline's opacity create an accessibility problem?

Tags: accessibility

I built a page that had an odd problem. When visitors arrived at the page and then used their keyboard's down-arrow to scroll, a dark line would appear around the main `article` (semantic HTML).

My attempt to create a minimal reproducible example only resulted in a simplified web page that does **not** have the problem. Obviously, that in itself is a clue about problems in the HTML/CSS, but I want to keep the topic on accessibility best practice.

REPRODUCING the bug: This is visible on the real page. From a desktop/laptop, at [this link](https://keithpurtell.com/top-down-boss.htm), use `Ctrl+F` to Find, then type in "StoneBridge" and you should immediately see that word highlighted. Carefully click the x to close the Find box (and nothing else). On my laptop, the black border appears around the body text. **Alternate:** Instead of the Find box, try turning on Chrome Web Tools. In the Elements box on the left, select `<article tabindex="-1" id="main">` Then, in the Styles box on the right, click on `:hov` and then check `:focus-visible`  That should turn on the black border (or outline).

I can force a change by using `article:focus-visible {outline-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .0);}` but even as an accessibility newbie I suspect that is not best practice.

A CSS code block that I imported to enable a skip link is most certainly the source of the dark line, so I have included that in the requested snippet below...

```css
/* ACCESSIBLE START */
.visible-on-focus {
position:absolute;
left:-10000px;
top:auto;
width:1px;
height:1px;
overflow:hidden;
}
.visible-on-focus:active, .visible-on-focus:focus {
border:none;
/* Visible in the full-color space */
box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,123,255,1);
/* Visible in Windows high-contrast themes */
outline-color:transparent;
outline-width:3px;
outline-style:dotted;
position:relative;
width:auto;
height:auto;
left:auto;
color:blue;
font-family:sans-serif;
font-size: 1.5rem;
font-weight:600;
line-height:inherit;
}
/* ACCESSIBLE END */
/* article:focus-visible {
outline-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .0);
} */
```

```html
<a href="#main" class="visible-on-focus">Skip to main content</a>
<header>
<h1>Heading level 1 here</h1>
<h2>Heading level 2 here</h2>
</header>
<nav></nav>
<article tabindex="-1" id="main">

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<h3>Heading level 3 here</h3>
<h4>Heading level 4 here</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<h3>Heading level 3 here</h3>
<h4>Heading level 4 here</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<h3>Heading level 3 here</h3>
<h4>Heading level 4 here</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

</article>

<footer>
  <div class="copyright">Copyright © 2022 by Web Developer. All Rights Reserved.</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: There's a difference between solving a problem and hiding a problem. You've not solved anything.

Comment: Could you please try and share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? A black outline sounds weird. It might be a focus outline, but if it’s around main, that would mean that main is being scrolled. Did you change overflow properties?

Comment: Andy, I'm doing that now this morning...

Comment: Andy, the imported code block has a line that setting overflow to hidden, but I'm not sure that's exactly what you meant.

Comment: Can you set up a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) so that we can reproduce what you're seeing rather than trying to imagine it based off a description?

Comment: Sean, I replace the previous pieces with a Stack Snippet. As mentioned, I'm now unable to reproduce the problem, but my question seems valid.

Comment: If I go to the live web page where this first happened, and open Chrome dev tools, and select `article` and then turn on the pseudo elements in dev tools, and check `:focus-visible` then I see the exact line. That's the closest I have gotten to "reproducing the problem."